# authenticity token and iphone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, client-server

I would like to add security measurements against CSFR for my iphone app, which uses a server as backend, and the same server also serves web requests. server is written in ruby on rails.

for regular requests I'm using an special kind of authenticity token hidden inside the form, which is posted with every request from that page to establish trust.

my problem is I cannot simulate this behavior from iphone since it doesn't actually pull a form before posting.

I've thought of something along the lines of first sending request to server to generate some kind of token and then adding it to requests, but still given someone stills the token + authentication cookie etc from the iphone, sniffs it out or something. I'm still exposed to CSRF.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [excellent post](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/) that should help to point you in the right direction.